# Text does not get highlighted in views using search api solr

Tags: views, search

I'm trying to highlight my search key in the result of a view using apache solr + search api solr module.

I've created a server + index using the search api solr module.

I've enabled highlighting option on both of them (In advanced setting on the server and within the filters in the index part)

I've created a view and exposed  Search: Fulltext search (exposed)

But the search word does not get highlighted.

When i'm using the "search api pages" module, i do get the search key highlighted.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a bug in search_api_solr version 1.6 (maybe previous versions too) that affects excerpts in Views. The highlighted text doesn't get returned in the Solr response. Patch has already been committed: https://www.drupal.org/node/1908990